# git-tfs starting from git

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I have an existing git repo that I am being forced to put in tfs. I would like to use the git-tfs tool, but can't figure out for the life of me how to do this. All of the examples I have seen start with git tfs clone, but I already have a git repo and would like to run "checkin" on it.

EDIT: I have tried cobbling together instructions based on the opposite scenario that I need. I have tried creating an empty project and adding that to tfs, then copy my code from git, but I lose my history (which I don't want). What I am looking for here is a set of steps to accomplish what I need.

Comment: What doesn't work? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, git-tfs works only by cloning a TFS repository.

I just hope that you've not a lot of branches to checkin into TFS otherwise it will be long an boring but doable!

First, create an empty repository in tfs.

**old solution** (still valid if you want to take this way...): <s>and clone it with tfs. You should be able to do it that easily and should have only one commit with no files in this new git repository.</s>

Now, add a remote toward your existing git repository and rebase the remote master onto the initial commit of the new repository.

**new solution:** Use [this script](https://gist.github.com/pmiossec/2421ffcc8011e873641b)

Then use 'git tfs rcheckin' to commit all the history. It should be very long :(

After that, if you have branches that you want to commit, and if you have the last version of git-tfs 0.17.1, extract the good revision and create a tfs branch with the command :

git tfs branch Name_of_my_branch

and rebase all the commits of the git branch and use rcheckin with :
git tfs rcheckin -i  Name_of_my_branch

Do that for all your branches and that should be good...

But I should add that if you've got merge commit, they will all be lost in the process :(
You won't have a as beautiful repository than you're existing git repository

PS :

- I'm really sorry for you to be obliged to use TFS after having used git
- Can't you use the new feature of TFS 2012 that will be released soon and which permit to have a git repository in TFS? 
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx and
  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx

Comment: i'll check this out tomorrow. since it's only 2012 and my company doesn't update anything until it's obsolete, no go on that hotness.

Comment: With "rebase the remote master onto the initial commit", I assume you mean `git rebase --onto master master@{0} myremote/master`

Comment: I tried and the commits were rebased onto master correctly, but master 'lost' the tfs-ancestor so that `git tfs rcheckin` failed. In [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) `tfs/default` appears as a completely isolated commit. On another attempt pulling from the original git-repository squashed the history into one merge-commit with `tfs/default` as one of the ancestors and rcheckin worked.

Comment: I don't know how you did your stuff but perhaps you should have tried to 'move' the tfs/default remote using `update-ref` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279814/how-can-i-clean-up-a-broken-history-with-git-tfs/17282547#17282547