# How can I clean up a broken history with git-tfs

Tags: git, git-tfs

I'm not sure how I managed to get into this state(*), but I've got some commits in my tfs/default remote branch that don't exist in TFS, so I want to get rid of them. So my history looks like this:

```
A--B--C--D tfs/default
```

... but commits B and C aren't actually changesets in TFS. As a result, when I checkout tfs/default I am out of sync with TFS because of commits B and C. Not good.

I figured I could fix it if I could somehow reset the tfs/default remote to A and do another "git tfs fetch" to end up with the actual history:

```
A--D tfs/default
```

but I'm not sure how to do that?

---

*) If it makes any difference, I think it involved using "git tfs shelve" on B and C, maybe followed by some commits and a "git tfs pull". But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've got half of the answer! You should reset the `tfs/default` to a previous step and fetch. There is no way to do that in git (if I know well) because that's not a normal case but we could still do that by editing git files... it's easy!

If you are sure that you don't want to keep the `B` and `C` commits (otherwise save them temporary by creating a local branch), just do the following:

- Go into your `.git` folder and look for the file `/refs/remotes/tfs/default`
- edit the file and replace the sha in the file with the sha of commit `A`
- fetch from tfs

And that should be good!

edit: can also be done with command line `git update-ref tfs/default SHAofcommitA`

Comment: Hmm wouldn't just `git reset --hard SHAofcommitA && git fetch` suffice ? As far as I know thats the proper way.

Comment: No, I don't think because he wants to move a remote managed by git-tfs and not a git branch...

Comment: but `git rev-update tfs/default SHAofcommitA` would have worked

Comment: @Phillipe: I think you mean `git update-ref tfs/default $SHA1`. rev-update is not a git command. And yes - update-ref is the correct way to edit the ref file.